# AMFPHP + Drupal Setup Error

Tags: php, apache-flex, drupal, content-management-system, amfphp

hopefully someone can help me with this headache I have.

I'm currently running Drupal 6 and am trying to integrate AMFPHP so I can do some stuff with Adobe Flex.

Anyway, I downloaded the AMPHP module and the other required modules.

I go to my domain/admin/build/services and see the following expected data:
Servers

```
* AMFPHP - /services/amfphp
* XMLRPC - /services/xmlrpc
```

Per instructions I click on AMFPHP and get presented the following data

> amfphp and this gateway are installed
>   correctly. You may now connect to this
>   gateway from Flash.
>
> Note: If you're reading an old
>   tutorial, it will tell you that you
>   should see a download window instead
>   of this message. This confused people
>   so this is the new behaviour starting
>   from amfphp 1.2.
>
> View the amfphp documentation
>
> Load the service browser

However, when clicking "Load the service browser"  I am presented the following error:

warning: require_once(modules/amfphp/amfphp/globals.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in modules/amfphp/amfphp.module on line 43.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found the problem.

My web host decided to create an .htaccess file for no good reason and it mucked the whole works up.

Deleting the .htaccess file fixed all the permission issues

Answer (score 0):

did you have your url rewrite rules in the .htaccess file?

was it in the htdocs dir or a subdir?

virtual host?

Comment: It was in a subdirectory.  

For some reason when I created the new folder - my webhosting provider decided to put the .htaccess file in that folder.  I hadn't seen it...it was the problem